# read dynamic memory allocated string (char*) from binary file C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, binaryfiles

I am trying to make students database by this types: (class Student)

```
class Student {           
    unsigned Id;//ID number
    char* name;// dynamic memory allocated name (size: 10)
    char* family;// dynamic memory allocated last name (size: 10)
    int gen;//gender
    unsigned MiddleTestGrade;// grade of the student in the middle test
    unsigned FinalTestGrade;// grade of the student in the final test
    double TotalGrade;// total grade of the student calculates automaticly (dont need to insert this as input)
};
```

I write all this information to a binary file using this command:(StudentData type is the Student class mentioned above)

```
file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&StudentData),sizeof(Student));
```

When I use the read command to get all the data from the file:

```
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&StudentData),sizeof (Student));
```

the result is that everything read good except for the dynamic allocated names.   These contain only the last name that i write to the file.

For example after I insert 2 students into the file:

> 12 Jhon Sna 1 95 100

and

> 77 David Gen 1 80 85

the result of the reading and printing will be:

> 12 David Gen 1 95 100

and

> 77 David Gen 1 80 85

When i use string (not dynamic allocated) everything works like it should :\

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not `std::string` with `std::fstream`

Comment: I used namespace std.

Comment: @user3688064 *don't* use `using namespace std;`. It is a bad habit.

Comment: I know but i must do it for my college assignments..

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Do you know what reinterpret_cast does?   In this case it does exactly what the OP needs to do to call file.write() or file.read().  The problem is the pointers contained within the structure not the reinterpration of the structure as an array of chars.

Comment: @DaleWilson: Yes, I do know what reinterpret_cast does. I was not sure if the OP did, hence the question in my comment. You actually state the precise motivation for why I guessed the OP would rely on some inexisting compiler magic.

Comment: OK. You could have phrased your comment better, but I'll leave it at that.  It's easy to appear rude in this type of format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have dynamically allocated data in a `struct`, you cannot use

```
file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&StudentData),sizeof(Student));
```

to write all the data in a file. That will just write the binary values of the pointers in the struct to the file. When you restore them, you will restore just the binary values, which will  lead to unpredictable behavior.

You need to write each field of the `struct` separately when there are dynamically allocated data and read them appropriately.

Code to write `Student`:

```
// Write Id
file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&(StudentData.Id)), sizeof(StudentData.Id));

// Get the length of name
// Write the length and then the name
size_t len = strlen(StudentData,name);
file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&len), sizeof(len));
file.write(StudentData.name, len);

// Get the length of family
// Write the length and then the family
len = strlen(StudentData,family);
file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&len), sizeof(len));
file.write(StudentData.family, len);

// Write the rest of the data
file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&(StudentData.gen)), sizeof(StudentData.gen);
file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&(StudentData.MiddleTestGrade)), sizeof(StudentData.MiddleTestGrade));
file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&(StudentData.FinalTestGrade)), sizeof(StudentData.FinalTestGrade));
file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&(StudentData.TotalGrade)), sizeof(StudentData.TotalGrade));
```

You have to read the data back one field at a time, allocating memory as necessary.

```
// Read the Id.
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&StudentData.Id),sizeof (Student.Id));

// Read length of the name
size_t len;
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&len), sizeof (len));

// Allocate memory for name.
Student.name = new char[len+1];

// Read the name and null-terminate it.
file.read(Student.name, len);
Student.name[len] = '\0';

// Read length of the family
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&len), sizeof (len));

// Allocate memory for family.
Student.family= new char[len+1];

// Read the family and null-terminate it.
file.read(Student.family, len);
Student.family[len] = '\0';

// Read the rest of the Student data
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&StudentData.gen),sizeof (Student.gen));
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&StudentData.MiddleTestGrade),sizeof (Student.MiddleTestGrade));
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&StudentData.FinalTestGrade),sizeof (Student.FinalTestGrade));
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&StudentData.TotalGrade),sizeof (Student.TotalGrade));
```